Maximise linear combination of roots of unity
Let $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ be nonnegative real numbers with $a_1+\dots+a_{n-1}=1$. Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/n}$ be a root of unity. Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i \omega^i$. Given that $S$ is a real number, find the maximum value of $S$.

My conjecture is that we should just pick $\omega$ and $\omega^{-1}$ and have a linear combination of $\frac{1}{2}$ of each, but I can't seem to formalise this claim...

Note that $S=(1-\sum_{k=1}^na_k)+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \omega^k$ and since $S=\Re S$ we have $$S=1-2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k\sin^2\pi k/n$$
Now we notice that $0 < \sin^2{\pi /n} \le \sin^2 \pi k /n$ for all $k=1,..n-1$ so since $a_k \ge 0, \sum a_k=1$ we get $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k\sin^2\pi k/n \ge  \sin^2{\pi /n}$$ hence $$S \le 1-2\sin^2 \pi/n$$ as conjectured by the OP with maximum $1-2\sin^2 \pi/n$ attained when $a_1=a_{k-1}=1/2$ (to have $S$ real)

First consider the relaxation where $S$ need not be real but you want to maximize
$\text{Re}\big(S\big) = \text{Re}\big(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \omega^k\big)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot \text{Re}\big(\omega^k\big)$
We have the point-wise inequality
$\text{Re}\big(\omega\big) \geq \text{Re}\big(\omega^k\big)$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$ with equality iff $k \in \big\{1,n-1\big\}$
summing over this point-wise bound yields
$\text{Re}\big(\omega\big)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot \text{Re}\big(\omega\big) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot \text{Re}\big(\omega^k\big)$
for any convex combination (selection of $\alpha_k$)
Returning to the original problem, since $S\in \mathbb R$, as OP conjectured we have
$\frac{1}{2}\big(\omega + \omega^{n-1}\big)=\text{Re}\big(\omega\big)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot \text{Re}\big(\omega\big) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k\cdot \text{Re}\big(\omega^k\big)=\text{Re}\big(S\big)=S$
for any allowable choice of $\alpha_k$
